# How can I transition width of content with width: auto?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an element whose width I'd like to animate when its contents change. It has `width: auto`, and this never changes. I've seen [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/4414003), but that's for transitioning between two values and one is set. I'm not manipulating the values at all, only the content, and I'd like my element's size to change with animation. Is this at all possible in CSS?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```css
.myspan {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.myspan:hover::after {
  content: "\00a0\f12a";
  font-family: Ionicons;
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <body>
    <span class="myspan">Hello!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like the changing size to animate when the user hovers over the element.

Comment: You can't animate `auto` with CSS only. Either use the "max-height" trick you've linked to or, on page load, run a small script which sets the final height

Comment: @LGSon How do I use the max width trick in this case, where both values in the transition are variable?

Comment: Plus, what do you mean "when the contents" change?...Why would they do that? If you're using JS to do that...then use JS to 'automate' the width change,

Comment: With the `max-width` trick you give it a value that is big enough to accommodate the widest. If you post your HTML and CSS I might be able to make a sample for you

Comment: @Paulie_D The contents change with a pseudo-element on hover (`elem:hover::after`)

Comment: I would hope not...pseudo-elements shouldn't contain **actual** content...they're intended for *styling*.

Comment: pseudo ?? ... now you definitely need to post your code

Comment: @Paulie_D In my actual code, it adds a "close" icon

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As I commented, one can't animate `auto` (yet), so either use the `max-width`/`max-height` trick, or, if you need it to be more exact, set the width using a script.

With the `max-width`/`max-height` trick, give it a value big enough to accommodate the widest.

Stack snippet

```css
.myspan {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.myspan::after {
  content: " \00a0\f12a ";
  font-family: ionicons;
  font-size: 80%;  
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: max-width .6s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.myspan:hover::after {
  max-width: 80px;
  transition: max-width 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="myspan">Hello!</span>
```

Comment: Right, do it on the pseudo element. I thought you were suggesting putting it on the main element, that's why I was confused ;)

Comment: @LukeTaylor If your close icon has a predefined width, you can just use width instead,and give the pseudo the final width icon included

Comment: Sorry, but can you give me a bit more help? Combining `overflow: hidden` with `display: inline-block` makes the ionicon disappear.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Updated my answer

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work when I tried to create a MCVE demonstrating the issue. I'll come back if I can't solve.

Comment: The issue was caused by my (silly) use of `line-height: 0` as a temporary hack to fix layout. Obviously, this would hide the icon when using `overflow: hidden;`. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's useful

```js
const expandBtn = document.getElementById('expand-btn');
expandBtn.onclick = (e) => {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: max-height;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
}

ul.active {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<button id="expand-btn">Expand</button>
<ul>
  <li>Hihi</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Rap star</li>
  <li>Hiphop</li>
</ul>
```